# Blank out duplicate column values in SQL Reporting Services

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

This has to be stupid easy to do, but I'm not seeing it.

I have a SQL Reporting Services (SQL 1008 R2) report.

I'm using a tablix to basically show:

```
COL 1 |  COL 2 |  COL 3 |  COL 4
----------------------------------
100   |  100   |  100   |  Item 1
100   |  100   |  101   |  Item 2
100   |  100   |  102   |  Item 3
100   |  110   |  110   |  Item 4
100   |  110   |  110   |  Item 4
100   |  110   |  111   |  Item 5
100   |  110   |  112   |  Item 6
```

But I want to suppress repeating values in those first two columns so it looks like this:

```
COL 1 |  COL 2 |  COL 3 |  COL 4
----------------------------------
100   |  100   |  100   |  Item 1
      |        |  101   |  Item 2
      |        |  102   |  Item 3
      |  110   |  110   |  Item 4
      |        |  110   |  Item 4
      |        |  111   |  Item 5
      |        |  112   |  Item 6
```

I thought it might be as easy as right clicking the column and selecting "Hide duplicate values", but I'm not seeing that.
I'll apologize now because I'm going to feel stupid when someone points out how easy it is to do or find.

Comment: Why don't you use groups instead? Then you can even beautify it by centering the group header cell.

Comment: That's exactly what I did about five minutes after posting this question.  I will leave my question up as a reminder and a badge of SHAME!

Comment: Well, FWIW let me answer the question anyway in case someone else wants the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is probably best to simply use groups, but if you want to keep it this way, try:

```vb
=IIf(Previous(Fields!Col1.Value) = Fields!Col1.Value, Nothing, Fields!Col1.Value)
```

Or you can set the textbox's `HideDuplicates` property to the containing group name (in your case, presumably `Tablix1_Details`)