# SSRS Row group header displayed on the same line as the first detail row

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a stepped tablix report in SSRS.
There are 2 row groups and I have it so the second row group header is in the same column as the first, this works fine.

What I am trying to do now is to line the first detail row up with the second row group header. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
Group1 Header
   Group2A Header        Detail Label     Detail Value
                         Detail Label     Detail Value
   Group2B Header        Detail Label     Detail Value
   Group2C Header        Detail Label     Detail Value

Group1 Header
   Group2B Header        Detail Label     Detail Value
   Group2C Header        Detail Label     Detail Value
```

If this isn't possible I will describe the goal of the report in the hopes someone may offer an alternative:

- Group one can be repeated many times
- Group two can only be either A B or C and all three can be present for the same Group one
- Group 2A if present will have a total row and a number of detail rows
- Groups 2B and 2C will only ever have a total row

Right now the query for this unions three different statistics (hence the three options for group 2), I did this strictly to try to make working with the Tablix easier, they are in fact three separate queries all with the same identifier (group 1).

Comment: My question is very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940805/blank-out-duplicate-column-values-in-sql-reporting-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after some trial and error the answer for [blank out duplicate column values in sql reporting services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940805/blank-out-duplicate-column-values-in-sql-reporting-services) offers a solution to my problem.

He mentions that the Hide Duplicates property can be used to do this, however it does not seem to work for the case of group headers.

However his usage of the IIf function does work, in the end I manually edited the expression for Group 2's header to be

```
=IIf(Previous(Fields!header.Value) = Fields!header.Value, Nothing, Fields!header.Value)
```